# "Í" on an american ipad keybord

Tags: keyboard

Is there a way to include a long í in the american keybord for an iPad or a shortcut for it?

I also have searched for a "0", but it will only work when transfering back to american keyboard and then back again.

Thank u!!!

Answer (score 1):

Long press on the "i" key, it will pop up as an option. This is true for several other keys, including the "o".

Comment: cmason is right, if you just hold down certain keys it gives the option of selecting variants of that letter. In some languages they commonly use multiple versions of the same character and you would do the same thing using a foreign keyboard. An example would be French where you commonly use an é instead of an e.